# Keep a line of floating DIVs constantly filled while inserting additional content

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've some floating preview-divs. There is some additional content in seperate divs which is hidden at first and opened on click. This additional content takes the whole width and naturally breaks the floating divs apart - I don't want to overlay the preview divs.

It looks like this right now:

[image]

Is there any way not to break the floats or to insert some of the following preview divs so that the actual line stays filled?

I would like to look it like this:

[image]

[Here is a FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/awv6gx4m/)

The HTML:

```
<div class="preview">1</div>
<div class="content"><h2>Additional Information</h2><p>Some content.</p>
</div>
<div class="preview">2</div>
<div class="content"><h2>Additional Information</h2><p>Some content.</p>
</div>
<div class="preview">3</div>
<div class="content"><h2>Additional Information</h2><p>Some content.</p>
</div>
<div class="preview">4</div>
<div class="content"><h2>Additional Information</h2><p>Some content.</p>
</div>
<div class="preview">5</div>
<div class="content"><h2>Additional Information</h2><p>Some content.</p>
</div>
<!-- ... and more like so //-->
```

The CSS:

```
.preview {
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
border: solid 10px #fff;
float: left;
background-color:#999;
text-align: center;
cursor: pointer;
}
.preview.active {
background-color:#CCC;
border-bottom-color: #CCC;
}
.content {
clear: left;
width: 80%;
margin: 20px 0;
padding: 5% 10%;
background-color:#CCC;
display: none;
}
```

jQuery-Script:

```
jQuery('.preview').click(function(){
if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $('.content.show').slideToggle(500, function(){
        $('.content.show').removeClass('show');
    });
}
else if ($('.preview').hasClass('active')) {
    $('.preview').removeClass('active');
    $('.content.show').slideToggle(500, function(){
        $('.content.show').removeClass('show');
    });
    $(this).addClass('active');
$('.active + .content').slideToggle(500, function(){
        $('.active + .content').addClass('show');
    });
}
else {
$(this).addClass('active');
$('.active + .content').slideToggle(500, function(){
        $('.active + .content').addClass('show');
    });
}   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is quick way for you to start with, using absolute positioning. It has glitches and is not finished, but as I said, just something to start with. I refactored the jQuery code, put the .content divs inside the .preview divs, and added some CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/awv6gx4m/2/

HTML:

```
<div class="preview">
    2
    <div class="content"><h2>Additional Information</h2>
        <p>Some content.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content {
    clear: left;
    margin: 20px 0;
    padding: 5% 10%;
    background-color:#CCC;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    left: 15px;
    width: 500px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery('.preview').click(function() {
    $('.content').not($(this).find('.content')).slideUp(500);
    $(this).find('.content').slideToggle(500, function(){
        $('.content.show').removeClass('show');
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Amar, thanks for the inspiration. It's not yet what I was looking for but you're right: it's a start.